# Choice of non-standard ephemeral ports

Tags: ip, port

This is somewhat related to - but different from - [Recommendation for a non-standard SSL port](https://serverfault.com/questions/130908/recommendation-for-a-non-standard-ssl-port) .

One answer there suggests that binding to 8443 is a valid example of an alternate HTTPS socket configuration. However, under [some Windows systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port#Range), 8443 falls within the ephemeral port range.

My questions are:

- Are there any risks associated with binding a service - such as sshd or httpd - to listen to a port in the ephemeral range?
- Could it interfere with the creation of outgoing sockets? In particular, will a listening socket and a connecting socket on the same address with the same port interfere, collide, or otherwise fail?
- Is it expected in such a case that a client request a new ephemeral port until it finds one that is available?

Comment: Other than all mentioned products being EOL, i suppose there shouldn't be a problem. Or just reconfigure the EPR on the systems. (or use modern OS/software, which ususally has an EPR of `49152 to 65535`)

Comment: (In Linux) I ran into something strange when using an eph port to listen on. I suspect, ports in the ephemeral range are treated differently when it comes to duration in TIME_WAIT state or how some options (SO_REUSE*) affect them, maybe? I couldn't find anything online, but noticed that when I used an eph port for a listener, and closed it, it took longer to close than when I used a non-eph port. This allowed a client (from a diff thread) to make a short-lived connection (which terminated but was left in TIME_WAIT), preventing server from binding again. This didn't happen with a non-eph port.